# Create an ASP.Net ComboBox with LoadOnDemand

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone have code or know how to create an asp.net combobox with LoadOnDemand functionality?

Comment: There are third-party ones available, but are you looking to build your own custom control, or just implement the functionality?

Comment: By *LoadOnDemand*, do you mean AJAX? Or cascading drop down lists? Or something else?

Comment: I built a User Control with a textbox, image(for the arrow), and a listbox (hidden, z-index = 1). I need it to load items on server side right before user makes a selection. My user control almost works.

Comment: I tried the Telerik radComboBox but i am creating many of them dynamically in the Page. It was very slow on postback because I had to re-create the controls everytime.

Comment: why not use auto-complete control instead...

Comment: @Naveed I am not familiar with "auto-complete" control. do you mean the ajax extenders?

Comment: @tmax Loading on demand for the RadComboBox is the easiest option if you have it.  You can also use it's client-side API.  I'd highly recommend this control if you have a license.  Otherwise, there are ways to build this type of control.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use ASP.NET AJAX Web services to stream the data, then populate the drop down with the items by adding items to the select element.

Check out this resource: http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-services

HTH.

Comment: Your suggestion may work, I need to read up a little more on it. Currently I am doing a PostBack through javascript "onfocus" event then loading the comobbox on server. then I forceably drop down the list so user can select item. but it is a little bit quarky.

Comment: Yes it can.  Using a web service can make it all client-side.  However, you may experience an issue that the ASP.NET dropdownlist control validates the items that exist in viewstate, and if that list differs from the previous post (if you postback new items that previously didn't exist on the server), it throws an exception.  FYI.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link would look good for you...

http://forums.asp.net/t/1503727.aspx

or alternatively, you may have a look at the ASP.Net `AutoCompleteExtender` for such a functionality. Sample here...

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

Comment: after researching the first link, i'm not sure i want to go down the jquery road with this. I am really looking for someone who is willing to show how to create this functionality. You'd think that microsoft would have provided this already...